# Copy object's attributes without having to repeat all the variable names?

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I'd like to change some of its attributes' names from `mixedCase` to `snake_case` without modifying the original object, and without having to re-write all the variable names twice. This example only includes two variables, but in my real code there are 10+ of them and it feels silly to repeat it all just to get two `mixedCase` variables into `snake_case`:

```
function do_stuff(data) {
  const { totalScore, position } = data;
  const params = { total_score: totalScore, position };
  return do_more_stuff(params);
}
```

Comment: It seems camelCase for variables and snake_case for functions. What do you want? You can call variables and functions as you want. What's the question/problem? I think this should be closed as primarily opinion based

Comment: I'd want to merge the two `const` lines without having to write all the variable names twice. How's that opinion based... @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Sure, the first line is unnecessary.  Just do `const params = { total_score: data.totalScore, position: data.position };`  Assuming I'm understanding the question properly.

Comment: I'm still writing all the variable names twice @Amy I understand that I will have to end up writing the mixedCase to snake_case variables twice, but I have like 10+ variables whose name don't change, I'd prefer not to write them twice

Comment: I don't see how it can be done any shorter.  Maybe `data.total_score = data.totalScore;  delete data.totalScore;`?  But this is no longer equivalent to the example code.  It's modifying the existing object rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use these functions:

```js
function snakeCase(s) {
    return s.replace(/([A-Z])/g, c => '_' + c.toLowerCase());
}

function snakeCaseKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce( (acc, key) =>
        Object.assign(acc, { [snakeCase(key)]: obj[key] }), {} );
}

// Sample use:
const params = snakeCaseKeys({totalScore: 1, position: 2});

console.log(params);
```

Comment: Or `return Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({[snakeCase(key)]: obj[key]})));`.

Comment: I seem to remember a comment on a previous answer of mine, that was almost the same ;-) Of course, correct, @torazaburo!